# Braintree payment method in magento2

Tags: magento2

How do I enable card save future as braintree credit card payment option in Magento2 on checkout page?

Comment: you again asked question, this is historical day....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour of using saving credits cards (Vault) depends on your Magento version.

Magento < 2.1 has and old implementation of Braintree payment method. Is more useful and secure to use Braintree payment method in Magento 2.1.

In both cases you need to go *Stores* -> *Configuration* -> *Sales* -> *Payment Methods* -> *Braintree* and when select *Vault enabled* -> *Yes*.

Perhaps, [this documentation](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/payment/braintree.html) will be helpful.

After refreshing Magento cache, saving credit card feature will be available on the payment step.

Note: Vault feature will be able only for registered customers.

**UPD**: More details in [payments methods](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/payments-integrations/bk-payments-integrations.html) documentation.